# Dynamically submitting a file upload form in IE10 using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a form whose only purpose is to upload files, but for user experience reasons, I need a nice-looking button that:

1. loads the file dialog
2. auto-submits the form when a file has been selected

The original solution was something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MCJaQ/2/), where you have a link that loads the file dialog, then listens for the dialog's `change` event to auto-submit the form:

```
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function () {
    // auto-submit form
    $("form").submit();
});

$("#my-nice-looking-button").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // load file dialog
    $("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
});
```

If you try that fiddle, it will work in IE9, Chrome, Firefox, etc., but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10. All the JavaScript functionality works, including the form's `submit` event getting fired. But, the browser never POSTs the form data to the server; it just sits there.

Is there some security safeguard or file upload limitation built into IE10 that prevents this from working?

Comment: With JoshMock's answer in mind, i'd suggest improving the functionality for modern browsers by using the file api and an ajax post, while falling back to your current functionality in IE<10 (and any other browser that doesn't support posting formData via ajax)

Comment: Yes, the eventual plan for this particular page is to upgrade it to use the File API. For the time being there was a more immediate need to "make it work in IE10" without the time for a full refactor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turns out, yes, IE10 does not let you both programmatically load a file dialog *and* automatically submit a form after a `change` event on a file dialog. Presumably one or the other will work, but not both. I haven't found any documentation to support this claim other than my own experimentation.

The solution I found was to use CSS to style the file dialog's button such that it was invisible, but laid over the top of the nice-looking button, so that when you *think* you're clicking on the button, you're actually clicking on the file dialog's "select" button:

```
input[type=file] {
    /* positioning strategies will vary depending on design */
    font-size: 25px;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: -10px;

    /* make it invisible! */
    opacity: 0;

    /* make the cursor act like it's hovering over an anchor tag */
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
```

Then you just need to listen for the `change` event and submit the form as before:

```
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function () {
    // auto-submit form
    $("form").submit();
});
```

Doing this means that you are "organically" loading the file dialog, and IE10 lets it happen and allows you to auto-submit the form.

This solution also works in WebKit and Firefox.

Comment: This is a restriction in place for all versions of IE.

Comment: @RayNicholus would love documentation/confirmation on that. This was (apparently) working in IE8 and IE9 using the old implementation.

Comment: I too ran into this issue only on IE10

Comment: I've had a similar issue on some mobile browsers (some older Android ones) - could this be causing this issue on them too?  The form would never submit...

Comment: Same here. We recently discovered this broken in our app, only on IE 10 (IE 9, Chrome, FF and Safari are unaffected). It's very odd, I can't find any more mention of this anywhere else on stack overflow. But the symptoms are dead on what I've seen. I'd just like to know more about the reasoning and the extent of this "bug" or "change".